# Asyncio consumer put element in queue as reference. They duplicates in loop

Tags: queue, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have implemented async paginated api requester with timeout, queue and multiple tokens (workers).
I have 3 workers (requesters), that consuming elements from queue. If result from request telling me that it is page 1 and total pages more than 1, my code put already used arguments to queue with another page param (from 2 to "total page"):

```
if result['page'] < result['total_pages'] and result['page'] == 1:
                for page in range(2, result['total_pages']+1):
                    request_kwargs['params']['page'] = page
                    queue.put_nowait(request_kwargs)
```

Everything works good until adding new arguments to the queue:
On the first for loop queue._queue (in debug) looks like:

```
deque([{'method': 'get', 'url': 'some_url', 'params': {'count': 100, 'page': 2}}])
```

But on the second for loop something goes wrong and adding new args overwrite previous and adding the same:

```
deque([{'method': 'get', 'url': 'some_url', 'params': {'count': 100, 'page': 3}},{'method': 'get', 'url': 'some_url', 'params': {'count': 100, 'page': 3}}])
```

...

On the 6th loop i have 6 similar elements in queue, with similar {'page':6}

Where am i wrong? Why does putting new request_kwargs overwrites existing ones?

Adding new elements works fine when i am just adding 'page' instead of dict with page in it.
That works fine:

```
if result['page'] < result['total_pages'] and result['page'] == 1:
                for page in range(2, result['total_pages']+1):
                    queue.put_nowait(page)
```

I think that adding new element to queue put reference to that element, not an instance. A have tried to add additional var before putting it into queue and deleting var after putting. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context that You are providing, You are actually putting the same object over and over again:

```
queue.put_nowait(request_kwargs)
```

You are not creating a separate `request_kwargs` variable in each loop pass. It is the same, **mutable** object every time the for loop iterates.
And moreover, You are performing explicit mutations of that variable on each loop pass:

```
request_kwargs['params']['page'] = page
```

This way, You are:

- changing all previous queue items, updating the page - cause each query item is actually the same object
- pushing the same queue item again

I think that such change should resolve Your issues:

```
import copy

# ...

if result['page'] < result['total_pages'] and result['page'] == 1:
    for page in range(2, result['total_pages']+1):
        request_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(request_kwargs)
        request_kwargs['params']['page'] = page
        queue.put_nowait(request_kwargs)
```

But using `deepcopy` always bring questions if my code is actually properly designed. And here it may not be.

Comment: I have find a solution without using deepcopy.  
`new_kwargs = dict(request_kwargs)`
`new_kwargs['params'] = dict(request_kwargs.get('params',{}))`
`new_kwargs['params']['page'] = page`
`queue.put_nowait(new_kwargs)`